# Replacing 9v DC adapter with a 9v battery on a network switch

Tags: switch, adapter

I have a small network switch powered by a 9v DC adapter. I want to connect multiple notebooks over cable outside, away from outlet. Would it be possible to connect the switch to a 9v battery?

EDIT: adapter puts out 600 mA.

Comment: This question may be better suited for the electronics SE. A 9V battery probably provides too little amperage for your switch. What amperage does your switch draw? What output amperage is your current 9V DC adapter rated for? As batteries drain, their voltage drops. You may need some kind of regulator between your battery and the switch to keep the voltage within the range the switch requires. You may end up being better off using 6 AA cells (or C or D cells) in series to reach 9V instead of a traditional 6F22 9V battery, which is really 6 tiny AAAA's in series inside a convenient package.

Comment: The battery might power the switch for an hour if you're lucky.  A big 12V car battery would be a better choice, with a DC-to-DC converter to bring the voltage down to 9V.

Comment: There are USB-powered network switches. They would drain the laptop battery a bit, unless plugged into an external battery. E.G. https://www.amazon.com/XtremPro-Powered-100Mbps-Ethernet-Network/dp/B074VZ236M/ref=sr_1_1_sspa

Answer (score 2):

Would it be possible? Probably, for short term use... like under an hour.

An average 9vDC battery supplies about 500mAh of capacity, so ignoring voltage drop over time that would equate to about 50 minutes of time it could power your switch in theory. I expect in real life it would drain much more quickly as 9V batteries are designed to average 15ma of current draw, not 600ma, so heat would become a very real factor as well.

An average D cell has 13000mAh of capacity, but only 1.5vDC so six cells in series would be required, and this would give about 21.6 hours of use in theory. Again, real word use would likely be much lower than that as well as voltage drops and temperatures rise.

Source: http://www.techlib.com/reference/batteries.html